# Kotlin JdbcTemplate Null

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to convert my application from java to kotlin and am using a mix of Java and Kotlin at the moment. I'm trying to convert my repository classes to Kotlin first. This is using Spring JDBC. Am I doing anything wrong ?

```
package com.meteor.coral.resources.useradministration.domain

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException

@Repository
open class AppUserJdbcRepository {

    @Autowired
    private var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate? = null

    fun findByFirstName(firstName: String): AppUser {
        print("hello")
        return jdbcTemplate!!.queryForObject("select firstname, lastname from m_appuser where firstname = ?", arrayOf<Any>(firstName), AppUserRowMapper())
    }



    internal inner class AppUserRowMapper : RowMapper<AppUser> {
        @Throws(SQLException::class)
        override fun mapRow(resultSet: ResultSet, i: Int): AppUser {
            val appUser = AppUser(resultSet.getString("firstname"),resultSet.getString("lastName") )
            return appUser
        }
    }
}
```

My test is still in Java

```
package com.meteor.coral.resources.useradministration;

import com.meteor.coral.UserAdministrationServiceApplication;
import com.meteor.coral.resources.useradministration.domain.AppUser;
import com.meteor.coral.resources.useradministration.domain.AppUserJdbcRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {UserAdministrationServiceApplication.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AppUserJdbcRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserJdbcRepository appUserJdbcRepository;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppUserJdbcRepositoryTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testAppFetch() {
        AppUser appUser = appUserJdbcRepository.findByFirstName("CARLO");
        LOGGER.info(appUser.getId() + "");
        LOGGER.info(appUser.getFirstname());
        LOGGER.info(appUser.getLastname());
    }
}
```

The jdbctemplate is always null.

```
hello
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.meteor.coral.resources.useradministration.domain.AppUserJdbcRepository.findByFirstName(AppUserJdbcRepository.kt:18)
    at com.meteor.coral.resources.useradministration.AppUserJdbcRepositoryTest.testAppFetch(AppUserJdbcRepositoryTest.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property injection with spring in kotlin requires the lateinit keyword:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate
```

Usually you want to do constructor injection though as this allows you to drop the Autowired annotion as wel as make it a val:

```
class AppUserJdbcRepository(private val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate){
```

For the sake of completeness: you shouldn't (ignoring rare corner cases) be using the '!!' operator in kotlin, since that is basically just falling back to javas nullability approach. At the very least in my experience it is a lot more debuggable to repolace it with a '?: throw MyCustomException("jdbcTemplate was null during initialization")', quite often I find that thinking about it also exposes unnecesary nullability.